# When I synaptic install a gnome applet in ubuntu, it doesn't show up in the 'add applet' program. How do I put these on my gnome bar?

Tags: ubuntu, gnome

They install okay, but I can't find them anywhere that they can be added to the toolbar.
Help?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Alt-F2, then `killall gnome-panel`. The gnome panel will disappear, then appear again. Now try adding your applets.

Comment: as it turned out I had to reboot to install a drive and in so doing it restarted everything and started working normally.